# Why do programmers put spaces inside braces?

Tags: coding-style

In my experience, it's common to see spaces put inside braces for one-line definitions, e.g. this function in JavaScript:

```
function(a, b) { return a * b; }
```

Is there any technical/historical reason that most programmers seem to do this, particularly given that spaces are not included inside parentheses?

Comment: It's to enhance readability...

Comment: Sure, it's a serious question! People are obviously intent on putting spaces inside {} but not () or []. So what's their motivation?

Comment: I have also wondered about this weird practice. I just try to understand that perhaps many programmers' education level is not high, so they have not learned about punctuation.

Comment: Although I wonder about this, I think this site may not be the right place to ask. In fact, I found a related question (that goes the opposite way): http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6512.

Comment: First off, it's not usually a good idea to put the text between `{}` all on the same line.  The usual scheme of `{`, newline, statement, newline ... `}` is far more readable in most cases and is "familiar".  If you *do* put it all on one line like that readability is greatly enhanced with the spaces.  And if you have an exceedingly long line a few spaces thrown in here and there helps your source editor find places to "fold" the line.  Note that this is not a trivial issue, as good readability greatly improves comprehension, thus significantly reducing bugs.

Comment: (Note that I will commonly insert a space after `(` in a function call, if the parameter is more than a single token.  Then, of course, a space after every `,` separating parameters.  This improves readability and also helps the source editor fold the line.)

Comment: @CharlesBrooking - A *statement* is different from a parameter or index.  It is a "higher order" construct and deserving of more "respect", in a way.

Answer (score 1):

Besides readability, in some languages, such as Verilog, identifiers can be escaped (by a \ at their beginning) so that they use special characters in their names. For example, the following names are legal identifier names in Verilog:

- q
- \q~             //escaped version which uses ~ in the name
- \element[32]    //a single variable (not part of an array) whose name is \element[32]

Such identifiers, should always terminate by space, otherwise the character after them would be considered as the identifier's name:

{ d, \q~ } // Concatenating d and \q~ in a vector
{ d, \q~} // Concatenating d and \q~} in a vector. Will generate a missing brace error.

Comment: Interesting case. But, assuming this affects () and [] too, it doesn't explain why {} is treated specially.

Comment: Yeah. Looks like a personal preference to me.

Comment: Did this weird practice of putting the space become widespread after Verilog's appearance?

Comment: I don't think the practice has anything to do with Verilog.  It's a common (and worthwhile) practice in the C-like languages.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are mostly used for readability.  Most of the coding styles will tell you to judiciously use whitespace in your code to make it more readable.

As an example, look at this statement: `*a = *b + *c;`.  Think how it will seem without the whitespace.